# Firebase Cloud Function to return data of 2 collections

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have written these 2 Cloud Functions to post data in the Cloud Firestore and they are working fine. Now I need to write a Cloud Function that should get data of both collections that were created above to post data. The data should be inside a new object and merged together

Desired JSON Output:

```
[
    {
        "course": "xxx";
        "client": "hello";
        "location": "lahore";
        "instructor": "ahsan";
        "bidding": true;
        "price": "400";
        "totalHours": "15";
        "maxStudents": "30",
        "listing": true,
        "closeDays": "20",
        "assistants": "hassan",
        "publicNotes": "nothing to say",
        "internalNotes": "nothing to say",
        "course": "xxx",
        "date": "25/9/2019",
        "hour": "3",
        "minute": "15",
        "timeofday": "PM",
        "tohour": "6",
        "tominute": "15",
        "totimeofday": "PM"
    }
]
```

//Schedule a class

```
exports.scheduleClass = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }
    else
    {
        if(req.body.course != null && req.body.client != null && req.body.location != null && req.body.instructor != null && req.body.bidding != null
        && req.body.price != null && req.body.totalHours != null && req.body.maxStudents != null && req.body.listing != null && req.body.closeDays != null
        && req.body.assistants != null && req.body.publicNotes != null && req.body.internalNotes != null
        || req.body.course != undefined && req.body.client != undefined && req.body.location != undefined && req.body.instructor != undefined && req.body.bidding != undefined
        && req.body.price != undefined && req.body.totalHours != undefined && req.body.maxStudents != undefined && req.body.listing != undefined
        && req.body.closeDays != undefined && req.body.assistants != undefined && req.body.publicNotes != undefined && req.body.internalNotes != undefined) {
            let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
            let newClass = {
                "course": req.body.course,
                "client": req.body.client,
                "location": req.body.location,
                "instructor": req.body.instructor,
                "bidding": req.body.bidding,
                "price": req.body.price,
                "totalHours": req.body.totalHours,
                "maxStudents": req.body.maxStudents,
                "listing": req.body.listing,
                "closeDays": req.body.closeDays,
                "assistants": req.body.assistants,
                "publicNotes": req.body.publicNotes,
                "internalNotes": req.body.internalNotes
            }
            usersClasses.add(newClass).then(snapshot => {
                res.send(200, {
                    "message": "Class was successfully created"
                })
            });
        } else {
            res.send(400, {
                "message": "All fields are required"
            })
        }
    }
});
```

//Add Time for classes

```
exports.addTimes = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.end();
  }

  else {
    if(req.body.course != null && req.body.date != null && req.body.hour != null && req.body.minute != null
    && req.body.timeofday != null && req.body.tohour != null && req.body.tominute != null && req.body.totimeofday != null
    || req.body.course != undefined && req.body.date != undefined && req.body.hour != undefined && req.body.minute != undefined && req.body.timeofday != undefined
    && req.body.tohour != undefined && req.body.tominute != undefined && req.body.totimeofday != undefined)
    {
      let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
      let newTimes = {
        "course": req.body.course,
        "tohour": req.body.tohour,
        "tominute": req.body.tominute,
        "totimeofday": req.body.totimeofday,
        "date": req.body.date,
        "hour": req.body.hour,
        "minute": req.body.minute,
        "timeofday": req.body.timeofday,
      }
      classtimesCollection.add(newTimes).then(snapshot => {
        res.send(200, {
          "message":"Time has been added"
        })
      });
    }
    else {
      res,send(400, {
        "message": "All fields are required"
      })
    }
  }
});
```

I am able to get data from one collection like this:

```
exports.getClassesSchedule = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }

    else
    {

        let allClasses = [];
        usersClasses.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    allClasses.push(doc.data());
                });
                res.send(allClasses);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error getting documents", err);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close you just need to make the other call. You'll want to use Promise.all to wait for both promises to be guaranteed to be complete before you start to collate the data.

```
exports.getClassesSchedule = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }

    else
    {
         let classTimes = []
         let promise1 = classTimesRef.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    classTimes.push(doc.data());
                });
                return classTimes
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error getting documents", err);
            });
        let allClasses = [];
        let promise2 = usersClassesRef.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    allClasses.push(doc.data());
                });
                return allClasses
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error getting documents", err);
            });
        return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(data => {
            let times = data[0]
            let classes = data[1]
            // Collate the data here

            return res.send()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please collate the data? I tried returning data through response directly from promise.all to see what it is returning at the moment but it gave me error 500 which means the function is not working properly. Also the name of my Collections are `classtimesCollection` and `usersClasses`. Also there was an error of closing bracket too at the end so i fixed it while deploying the functions but it still isn't working